# search users by their email id on facebook using connect api

Tags: facebook

I need to search users in facebook by their email id's. I could not find anything relevant to this.

I have seen an application using *facebook.users.getByEmail* method but I am not able to find more about it.

Please suggest.

--
Errata:
`>` By search I meant if I have a users email id then I need to find *uid* of that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

email property accessed just after you get special permission to retrieve email. so it's impossible.
more details here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Communicating_with_Users_via_Email

Comment: >> "By search I meant if I have a users email id then I need to find uid  of that user."

doesn't matter. you can get access to email property for any reason just after special permission.

Comment: @zerkms: One question. Do you have any idea what facebook.users.getByEmail does ?

Comment: i cannot find in facebook api method with such name :-( http://wiki.developers.facebook.com

Comment: I found reference for this method in forums http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=44884

Comment: read again that sentence "The method is:

facebook.users.getByEmail

We have a specific use case for for this method and would to put this to Facebook."

Comment: I read again. Found a contradicting sentence "....like to contact someone about gaining access to a API method which is currently not public - but used by some other none Facebook companies."

Comment: this is theirs proposal. this method exists only in their minds.